# Convert a decimal data field to hexadecimal using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, sh

Who can correct this command to get the desired output :

input : "1|2|30|4"

```
echo "1|2|30|4" | awk -F, -v OFS=| '{print $1,$2; printf "%04X", $3; print $4}'
```

Output expected :

```
1|2|001E|4
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "1|2|30|4" |
    awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{print $1, $2, sprintf("%X", $3), $4}'
1|2|1E|4
```

Comment: echo "1|2|30|4" | awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{x=sprintf("%04X", $3); print $1, $2, x, $4}'

Comment: It works +1. You could do it even shorter with:
`'{print $1, $2, sprintf("%04X", $3), $4}'`

Comment: you have inspired me. Here is the final version that i'm looking for : echo "1|2|30|4" | awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{$3=sprintf("%04X", $3); print $0}'

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "1|2|30|4" | awk -F"|" '{printf "%s|%s|%04X|%s", $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

Output:

```
1|2|001E|4
```